# Javascript querySelector

Tags: javascript, regex, selenium, robotframework

In Robot I have a keyword that inputs the name of the associate in the search field, then i submit the form. It currently works only for a specific test account. I want to make that dynamic to work no matter what name I type. Of-course as long as the name exist in our system

```
Execute JavaScript  document.querySelector("#add_associate_089 > img").click();
```

add_associate_089 > img = the image we display next to the associate name in the results page contains the record id

Im trying to make add_associate_**089** dynamic this is the associate id we have in our database.

Any suggestions as to how I can accomplish this in robot?

Comment: Not understanding why you can't just do `querySelector("#add_associate_" +wantedNumber+" > img")`

Comment: What exactly the issue you're encountering is is not clear.

Answer (score 2):

You can try: `[id^="add_associate_"] > img` - this will select anything where id starts with that.